# Canvas size not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to make a graph with Chart.js but the canvas is not changing in size no matter what I set the width and height of the canvas to be. This is source code I found in the examples which I am currently using (which still doesn't work):

```js
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: In [the manual](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) they say there is an `responsive` option, if you set it to false, well... it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

as Kaiido said I have to set the responsive option

like this

```
  options: {
     responsive: false
 }
```